# Crontab x minutes past every hour on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, crontab

I haven't been able to find an example of how to run a command in crontab at 5 minutes past every hour.

I assumed that this would work

```
5 */1 * * *
```

But it doesn't run.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just use `5 * * * *`

the others are wilcards

if you wanted at 1:05am only that would be `5 1 * * *`

Answer (score 1):

You should use  */5 */1 * * *

You should try yourself [here](https://crontab.guru/#*/5_*/1_*_*_*).

Comment: `5 * * * *` is simpler!

Comment: That would be _every_ 5th minute. The question was 5 minutes past every hour, which is not the same thing

Comment: this should be the correct answer for the question